# PYTHON | Extracting specific text from variable [regex]

Tags: python, string, extract

I have this text:
Intel Core i5-1235U 3.3GHz (10C 12T • 12MB Cache • up to 4.4GHz)

and i want to extract everything after the word "Core" till the next backspace
"i5-1235U"

the pattern of the text can be changed, like
Intel Core i7-1255U 3.3GHz (10C 12T • 12MB Cache • up to 4.4GHz)
where I want the
"i7-1255U"

or
Intel Core i7-920P 3.3GHz (10C 12T • 12MB Cache • up to 4.4GHz)
where I want the
"i7-920P"

and so on..

it will always start with "Intel Core" and will have "x.xGhz" after the word I want to extract

i5?.+U

but it works specifically with
"Intel Core i5-1235U 3.3GHz (10C 12T • 12MB Cache • up to 4.4GHz)"
and I want it to work on many variations :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try code below:

```
text = 'Intel Core i7-920P 3.3GHz (10C 12T • 12MB Cache • up to 4.4GHz)'

cpu_type = (text.split('Core')[1]).split()[0]
```